# c# how would i Show() every form that i add?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am creating instances of Form1() on the fly.

i need to be able to show it every time i open it. the result would be a bunch of popping up forms. here is my code. how do i show the form as soon as it is created>?

```
List<Form1> forms = new List<Form1>();
    string analyte;
    for(int i = 0; i < cbAnalytes.Items.Count; ++i)
    {
        cbAnalytes.SelectedIndex = i;
        analyte = cbAnalytes.Text;
        // Process the object depending on the type
        forms.Add(new Form1(dateStart.Value.ToShortDateString(), dateEnd.Value.ToShortDateString(), cbQCValues.Text, analyte, cbInstruments.Text));


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to specifically call each form's `Show()` method.
Namely like so:

```
List<Form1> forms = new List<Form1>();
string analyte;
for(int i = 0; i < cbAnalytes.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    cbAnalytes.SelectedIndex = i;
    analyte = cbAnalytes.Text;
    // Process the object depending on the type
    Form1 aform = new Form1(dateStart.Value.ToShortDateString(), dateEnd.Value.ToShortDateString(), cbQCValues.Text, analyte, cbInstruments.Text);
    aform.Show();
    forms.Add(aform);
}
```